# spring boot cmd line cron expression java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I do have an argument with my Spring Boot powered web application. I'm trying to override a @Scheduled cron expression from the command line, but spring responds with a java.lang.IllegalStateException.

```
Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'work': 
Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in "0")
```

I have a Spring Component with a Scheduled Annotation:

```
@Scheduled(cron="${myapp.cron}")
public void work() {
    ...
}
```

There is an application.properties file like this:

```
myapp.cron=0 0 1 * * *
```

I'm bundling the application with maven to a jar file. The application runs on an ubuntu machine with Java 8 as an init task (/etc/init/myapp.conf).

```
description "My app"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
respawn limit 10 5

setuid <USER>
setgid <GROUP>

script
    java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar /opt/myapp.jar \
         --server.port=4014 \
         --server.address=127.0.0.1 
         --logging.file=/opt/myapp.log \
         --logging.level.root=INFO
end script
```

Until this point everything is fine. Adding the following line gives the above mention exception.

```
--myapp.cron=0 0 8 * * *
```

Any ideas? What's wrong?

Cheers, 
Kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kai,

You're passing in the `0 0 8 * * *` as command line parameter in order to get it in the Spring environment. However, your app only gets the first `0` as variable value, hence the exception about the required 6 parts. Surround the value with quotes instead:

```
--myapp.cron="0 0 8 * * *"
```

Answer (score -1):

create a xyz.properties file under src/main/resouce folder.

```
cron.open.status.mgr.schedule=10 15 0 15 * ?
```

and do something like below

```
@Component
public class OpenStatusManagerScheduler {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${open.status.mgr.schedule}")
    public void scheduleStatusTaskWithCronExpression() {}
}
```

Comment: Downvote because: The question was about how to override a specific property from the command line.